# With what force can a solenoid pull?

Tags: solenoid, homework

I am conducting an experiment, and a hugely important part of the experiment is a solenoid and an iron rod. If the solenoid has current going through it, and I place the iron rod so that it is not fully inside the solenoid, it will pull it inside the solenoid. It is this property of the solenoid that I want to use for my experiment. To do it, I need to know the numerical value of the force exerted on the iron rod by the solenoid at any particular position. After some research, I found an expression for a force that might work, but about which I am a little unsure about. The equation states that F=

[image]

Where N is the number of turns, I is current, A is the area of the solenoid (cross-sectional area I assume, though I could be wrong), and g is g is the length of the gap between the coil and the iron.

I do not have much experience with this topic, but intuitively, this equation seems to give me the average force acting on over the entire range of movement, rather than the force that acts at a particular point, because it seems to me that the force increases the further in the iron rod is sucked. So I guess what I am asking, is how to modify this equation to give the force at a single instant, or if this is even the equation to use? Or is this more of a calculus question and should I put it on mathstackexchange?

Comment: In general, the force on an armature (the moving part of a solenoid or motor) is proportional to how rapidly the total energy of the magnetic field changes (i.e., its gradient) as a function of the position of the armature. It's a complicated 3-D field problem, and I don't have a simple formula for you.

Comment: That g, which is the length of the gap between the coil and the iron, varies as the iron gets pulled in

Comment: This may help you calculate the forces: http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys313/lectures/sol/sol_f01_long.html     ...you are complicating the calculation by only partially inserting the Iron core. Typically you would have the Iron core right through the coil and energizing it would center the core in the field.

Comment: _"After some research, I found an expression..."_ - where did you find it?